# Definição do dia da semana no GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime, calendário-gregoriano

Eu tenho o seguinte código que é responsável por criar um GregorianCalendar para a manipulação de uma data.

```java
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");  
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);  
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);
calendar.setTime(new Date());

System.out.println(calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Porém o que é exibido é "2", ou seja, segunda-feira. Qual o motivo disso acontecer?

Comment: Detalhe, `getInstance` é um método definido em `Calendar`, e não em `GregorianCalendar`. Java permite chamar métodos estáticos através de "herança", mas, na prática, você está chamando o método de `Calendar`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Até Java 7**

Para propósito da discussão a seguir, note que a França começa a semana na segunda feira enquanto os EUA começam no domingo.

O código abaixo está sendo executado no REPL de Scala, chamando as bibliotecas Java com o seguinte import:

```shell
scala> import java.util.{Calendar, Locale, TimeZone}
import java.util.{Calendar, Locale, TimeZone}
```

**TimeZone não contém a informação correta sobre o primeiro dia da semana**

Como pode se observar:

```shell
scala> "startDayOfWeek[^,]*".r findFirstIn TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris").toString
res0: Option[String] = Some(startDayOfWeek=1)

scala> "startDayOfWeek[^,]*".r findFirstIn TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo").toString
res1: Option[String] = Some(startDayOfWeek=1)

scala> "startDayOfWeek[^,]*".r findFirstIn TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles").toString
res2: Option[String] = Some(startDayOfWeek=1)
```

**Não há forma de se extrair dia da semana de um TimeZone**

Usando tab-completion para se obter os métodos disponíveis:

```shell
scala> TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris")
res3: java.util.TimeZone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transit
ions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMod
e=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endT
ime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]

scala> res3.
asInstanceOf           clone                  getDSTSavings          getDisplayName         getID
getOffset              getRawOffset           hasSameRules           inDaylightTime         isInstanceOf
observesDaylightTime   setID                  setRawOffset           toString               useDaylightTime
```

Nada disso retorna a informação desejada (que está incorreta de qualquer forma)

**Locale pode ser usado para setar o primeiro dia da semana**

Como podemos observar:

```shell
scala> Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE).getFirstDayOfWeek
res8: Int = 2

scala> Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek
res9: Int = 1
```

**Mas isso não funciona para nós Brasileiros**

```shell
scala> Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR")).getFirstDayOfWeek
res10: Int = 2
```

Pergunte a um brasileiro qualquer qual é o primeiro dia da semana, e ele provavelmente irá dizer Domingo. Tanto é que segunda feira é o primeiro dia *útil*. Infelizmente, não há nenhuma norma brasileira sobre isso, e a norma internacional (assim como o costume na maior parte do mundo, excluindo Estados Unidos) dita Segunda Feira como primeiro dia.

Na norma ABNT que seria a mais relevante, NBR 5892:1989, não há declaração de qual é o primeiro dia da semana, mas os dias da semana são listados de segunda a domingo quando a norma lista as abreviaturas.

Na wikipedia, a [discussão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discuss%C3%A3o:Domingo) vai longe!

Além disso, o Domingo é parte do "fim-de-semana", não é?

Por isso, e embora nós Brasileiros usemos calendários começando com o Domingo, acho difícil alterar isso. Mas, para quem estiver suficientemente indignado e motivado, uma ajuda:

- [Link para submissão de bugs](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/);
- Um [bug anterior](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7060794) reportando esse tipo de problema -- no caso, o bug era inválido, mas você pode usar ele como referência, e copiar o programa usado nele para demonstrar o problema.

**Java 8**

As novas facilidades de horário e data do Java 8 apresentam o mesmo comportamento do Java 7:

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

// ...
  WeekFields brWeekFields = WeekFields.of(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
  DayOfWeek brFirstDayOfWeek = brWeekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek(); // MONDAY
```

Mas se você quer semanas começando no Domingo, use o seguinte:

```java
  WeekFields brWeekFields = WeekFields.SUNDAY_START;
  DayOfWeek brFirstDayOfWeek = brWeekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek(); // SUNDAY
```

Da mesma forma que em Java 7, datas obtidas a partir do timezone (`zoneId` em Java 8) não tem informação a respeito do primeiro dia da semana. Ao contrário do Java 7, entretanto, nem existem métodos que permitam fazer essa indagação em nada derivado a partir do `zoneId`.

Comment: "Pergunte a um brasileiro qualquer qual é o primeiro dia da semana, e ele provavelmente irá dizer Domingo." Será? Eu diria segunda.

Comment: @bfavaretto "Provavelmente" é usado aqui para indicar grande probabilidade, e não certeza. Olhando [por aí](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110524075812AAoGkFf), não consegui achar ninguém dizendo segunda.

Comment: @bfavaretto Desde criança fui ensinado que o primeiro dia da semana é o domingo, talvez por causa da tradição cristã onde o domingo é o primeiro dia da criação.

Comment: Para culturas judaicas e cristãos, sábado é o sétimo dia da semana. Dica: não queira entrar numa discussão sobre isso com um Adventista do Sétimo Dia.

Comment: Para mim o primeiro dia é o domingo. As palavras "Segunda, Terça, Quarta, Quinta e Sexta" são bastante sugestivas de que Sétima=Sábado e Primeira=Domingo.

Comment: Por algum motivo todos os aplicativos e OSes em que eu já usei, e reconfirmei em boa parte, a semana se inicia no domingo usando o locale Brasil. Eu compartilho da idéia da semana se iniciar no domingo, sustentado tanto pelo argumento do @Victor quanto pela grande maioria (tudo que eu já vi exceto o comment do bfavaretto) indicando que aqui a semana começa no domingo mesmo. De qualquer forma, ainda não encontrei prova "documental" em nenhuma das duas vertentes que seja específica para o Brasil.

Comment: @Bacco Eu não descobri **porque** e nem **quem** "decidiu" que é domingo para pt_BR, mas deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449122/112052) detalhando de onde o Java tira essas informações (um pequeno detalhe que não tinha nas outras respostas)

Comment: @VictorStafusa Em outros idiomas não existe essa associação (pelo menos não tão direta assim) entre os dias da semana e a respectiva "ordem"/numeração (em inglês e japonês, por exemplo, domingo é literalmente "o dia do sol"). Se fosse apenas uma questão linguística, os locales en_US e en_GB (respectivamente, inglês americano e inglês britânico) teriam as mesmas regras, mas o primeiro retorna Domingo e o segundo retorna Segunda: https://ideone.com/cAs8uc :-)

Answer (score 10):

O primeiro dia da semana, retornado pela função `getFirstDayOfWeek()` [é definido pelas configurações do *locale* atual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()). Por exemplo, no brasil a convenção é que o primeiro dia da semana é a segunda-feira, enquanto nos EUA a semana começa no domingo:

[image: Calendário EU]
[image: Calendário Brasil]

**Edit:** Se você deseja mover a data atual do calendário para o primeiro dia da semana em que ele se encontra:

```shell
calendar.setWeekDate(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                     calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR),
                     calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek())
```

Ou simplesmente:

```shell
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Qual é a convenção que diz que o primeiro dia da semana é segunda-feira?

Comment: De acordo com o [artigo na wikipédia sobre a segunda-feira](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segunda-feira), a segunda feira é definida como o primeiro dia da semana pelo padrão ISO 8601. O texto das normas ISO não é disponível públicamente (ele precisa ser comprado), mas a [página na wikipedia em inglês sobre o ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) parece confirmar essa informação: *"The ISO week-numbering year starts at the first day (Monday) of week 1 (...)"*

Answer (score 1):

O [`TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) não tem nada a ver com a definição de semana. Isso é controlado pelo [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Tanto que se você fizer isso:

```
for (String zone : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zone);
    TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);
    System.out.println(zone + "=" + calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
}
```

O resultado de [`getFirstDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()) será o mesmo para todos os timezones. Já se você fizer isso:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo");
TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
for (Locale loc : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    Locale.setDefault(loc);
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);
    System.out.println(loc + "=" + calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
}
```

O resultado de `getFirstDayOfWeek()` poderá ser 1, 2 ou 7, dependendo do `Locale` utilizado. Aliás, o `TimeZone` não faz diferença neste código, eu poderia chamar simplesmente `getInstance()` (ou ainda `getInstance(loc)` em vez de usar `Locale.setDefault`), que o resultado seria o mesmo: o *locale* é que define qual será o primeiro dia da semana, independente do timezone usado.

<sup>*Também retirei a linha `calendar.setTime(new Date())`, pois é redundante: `getInstance` já pega a data/hora atual, e setar um `new Date()` (que também é a data/hora atual) é desnecessário.*</sup>

---

Quando você cria um [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), ele vai buscar dentro da própria JVM a informação sobre o primeiro dia da semana, baseado no *locale* informado. Se nenhum é passado para [`getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()), usa-se o *default* da JVM (que mudamos com [`Locale.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)) no código acima).

Basicamente, a JVM possui vários arquivos de *properties* contendo a respectiva informação de cada *locale*. Mas nem todos os *locales* possuem um arquivo específico, e para estes existe um *default* que é usado como *fallback*.

No Java 7, por exemplo, o arquivo *default* (usado como *fallback*) é [esse](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/util/resources/CalendarData.properties), e veja que ele possui o seguinte conteúdo:

```
firstDayOfWeek=1
minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1
```

E como não existe um arquivo específico para o *locale* `pt_BR`, o código abaixo - testado no JDK 1.7.0_80 - imprime 1 ([que corresponde a domingo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY)):

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR")).getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

<sup>*Só achei curioso que na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134/112052) o resultado foi 2, pois testando no Java 7 e 8, eu obtive 1*.</sup>

Já usando outro *locale*:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en", "GB")).getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

Neste caso o resultado foi 2 ([segunda-feira](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY)), pois no Java 7 existe um [arquivo de *properties* específico para o *locale* `en_GB`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/util/resources/CalendarData_en_GB.properties), no qual o valor de `firstDayOfWeek` é 2.

Obs: nos links acima (que correspondem ao código do OpenJDK) não existe um *properties* para `pt_BR`, mas na JVM que estou usando na minha máquina existe. De qualquer forma, o que importa é que esta informação sempre é buscada na JVM.

---

No Java 8 é similar: existe um [*properties* específico para `pt_BR`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/util/resources/pt/CalendarData_pt_BR.properties) (no qual `firstDayOfWeek` é 1) e também existe [outro para `en_GB`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/util/resources/en/CalendarData_en_GB.properties) (com `firstDayOfWeek` igual a 2), além de um [*properties default*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/sun/util/resources/CalendarData.properties) usado como *fallback* (com `firstDayOfWeek` igual a 1).

Aliás, testando no Java 8 (JDK 1.8.0_202) também obtive um resultado diferente da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134/112052):

```
WeekFields brWeekFields = WeekFields.of(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
DayOfWeek brFirstDayOfWeek = brWeekFields.getFirstDayOfWeek(); // SUNDAY
```

No [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/7V9f9V) o código acima também retorna "domingo".

---

A partir do Java 8, o JDK [passou a buscar uma maior compatibilidade](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#api) com o [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org), um repositório de informações relacionadas aos *locales*. Uma das informações definidas pelo CLDR é - adivinhe - [a definição do primeiro dia da semana](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Week_Data). Estas definições ficam no arquivo de [`supplementalData`](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml):

```xml
<firstDay day="mon" territories=" 001 AD AI AL AM AN AT AX AZ BA BE BG BM BN BY CH CL CM CR CY CZ DE DK EC EE ES FI FJ FO FR GB GE GF GP GR HR HU IE IS IT KG KZ LB LI LK LT LU LV MC MD ME MK MN MQ MY NL NO NZ PL RE RO RS RU SE SI SK SM TJ TM TR UA UY UZ VA VN XK"/>    
<firstDay day="fri" territories="MV"/>    
<firstDay day="sat" territories="AE AF BH DJ DZ EG IQ IR JO KW LY OM QA SD SY"/>    
<firstDay day="sun" territories=" AG AR AS AU BD BR BS BT BW BZ CA CN CO DM DO ET GT GU HK HN ID IL IN JM JP KE KH KR LA MH MM MO MT MX MZ NI NP PA PE PH PK PR PT PY SA SG SV TH TT TW UM US VE VI WS YE ZA ZW"/>
```

Não testei para todos, mas veja que para `BR` (Brasil) o primeiro dia da semana é domingo ("sun") e para `GB` (Reino Unido), é segunda-feira ("mon"), que batem com os resultados do Java. No caso do Java 8, tanto `Calendar` quanto [`WeekFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) usam os mesmos *properties* e os resultados batem com o `suplementalData` acima.

Mas vale lembrar que, como essas informações ficam embutidas na JVM, elas podem mudar de uma versão para outra, [como aconteceu com alguns locales no Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572187) - afinal, o CLDR está sempre sendo atualizado, e o Java tenta acompanhá-lo na medida do possível (além disso, o CLDR só passou a ser a fonte *default* de informações dos *locales* [a partir do Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-983469B6-9BB5-48CA-B71D-8D7012B2F3CA)).

O único mistério, para mim, é como chegaram nesses valores. Alguém teve que decidir qual é o primeiro dia da semana para cada um desses locales. Ou seja, esta resposta ajuda a explicar de onde vem esses dados, mas não **porque** os dados são exatamente esses.